# How to list all of variations without STL C++

Tags: c++

I have got stuck.

Could anyone help me?
My problem is that I have no idea, how to make listing variations without STL.

Example:

```
 Input : a[3] = {1, 2, 3}
 n = 2
```

Output:
                        1 1;    2 1;    3 1;
            1 2;    2 2;    3 2;
            1 3;    2 3;    3 3;

I can't use loops, because the input can be as big as I declare, and n is a variable too.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why can't you use loops?  This seems like a perfect candidate for loops plus perhaps a bit of recursion.

Comment: You *can't* do this for an arbitrary n without loops (assuming you don't use gotos). FYI, loops aren't part of the STL.

Comment: Containers, algorithms, I/O without STL in C++ is essentially asking for the code in C.

Comment: It seems you know a method to solve this with STL, please enlighten me. I only know how to do this with loop and/or recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are posting spoilers anyway, let me post a nice optimized version of the algorithm I originally implemented to answer [Number crunching in Ruby (optimisation needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680725/number-crunching-in-ruby-optimisation-needed/5682791#5682791)

Have fun

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

inline void recursive_permute2(const char* b, char* const m, char* const e, const char* domain)
{
    if (m<e)
        for (; *domain; ++domain)
        {
            *m = *domain;
            recursive_permute2(b, m+1, e, domain);
        }
    else
        puts(b);
}

inline void recursive_permute(char* const b, char* const e, const char* const domain)
{
    *e = '\0';
    recursive_permute2(b, b, e, domain);
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 2;
    char buf[n+1];

    recursive_permute(buf, buf+n, "123");
}
```

Comment: PS. if formatting is of concern, you can replace `puts(b)` by your own formatting function

Answer (score 0):

At one time, I would have recommended that you get this from snippets.org, but it has now departed this realm (as, it appears, has Bob Stout, its former curator). As noted in the comments, I did not write this, but unlike much of what's posted, it has been tested to at least a reasonable degree.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/*  chouse_n ( char *strng, int length) returns a pointer to a string of   */
/*  length characters chosen from "strng" , duplicate chars in "strng" are */
/*  significant.  Strings are generated in lexical order.                  */
/*  First call, call with *strng. each subsiquent call, call with NULL,    */
/*  returns one combination. Calls after all combinations have been        */
/*  returned return NULL.  Will return NULL for errors.                    */
/*  not very defensive (i.e. WILL BREAK)                                   */

/*  dave chapman aug '91  released to public domain                        */

char *chouse_n( char *strng, int length);

char *chouse_n( char *strng, int length)
{
      static char *str;
      static char *curr;
      static char *pos;       /* for each char in curr(ent string),
                                 its pos in str                            */
      static int  counts[256];
      int i,j;

      if (0 >= length)
            return NULL;

      if (NULL != strng)
      {
            str = malloc(strlen(strng)); /* first call, prep string for use */
            curr = malloc(2 * length + 1);
            pos = curr + length +1;

            for (i = 0; i < 256; counts[i++] = 0)
                  ;
            for (i = 0; strng[i]; i++)
                  counts[strng[i]]++;

            for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                  if (counts[i])
                  {
                        str[j] = i;
                        counts[j++] = counts[i];
                  }
            }
            str[j] = '\0';      /* str is string of distinct chars in order */
                                /* counts[] holds count of each char        */

            /* take first length chars */

            for (i = 0,j = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                  curr[i] = str[j];
                  pos[i] = j;
                  if (!(--counts[j]))
                        j++;
            }
            curr[i] = '\0';
            return curr;
      }
      /* if called with "mississippi",5;
         str -> "imps"
         curr -> "iiiim"
         counts -> 0,0,2,4;
         pos -> 0,0,0,0,1;   */

      /* go back to front */

      for (j = length; j > 0;)
      {
            counts[ pos[--j]]++;                      /* "replace" char */

            /* look for a new char for curr posit. */

            for ( i = ++pos[j]; str[i] && ! counts[i]; i++)
            ;
            if (0 != (curr[j] = str[i]))              /* found a char   */
            {
                  --counts[i];
                  pos[j] = i;

                  /* placed char, fill out rest of string  */

                  for (++j, i = 0; j < length; j++)
                  {
                        for ( ; !counts[i]; i++)
                              ;
                        curr[j] = str[i];       /* first available char */
                        --counts[i];
                        pos[j] = i;
                  }
                  return curr;
            }
            /* no more chars for this pos ; go back one */
      }
      /*  done */
      return NULL;
}

main()
{
      char  *str = "aabbccdd";
      int i,j;

      j = 0;
      i =  5;
      puts(chouse_n( str, i));
      while (NULL != (str = chouse_n(NULL, i)))
      {
            ++j;
            printf(" %s  %d\n",str,j);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework, so I don't want to give you just a working bit of code. But I can try to guide you down the right path algorithmically.

Let's start with a stack of arrays that is initially empty. Now, for each element of `a`, create a new list to hold it. Now we have three lists in your case: `[1], [2], [3]`. Push each of those lists onto a stack or queue to hold them. Now, pop one off the stack. Let's say it's `[1]` that we get first. That leaves the stack holding `[2]`, and `[3]`. Examine the element you just popped (`[1]`). Is it long enough? No. You asked for 2 items, and it only has one. So now you iterate over all elements of `a` again and add each to a fresh copy of the node you popped. That gives you three new nodes: `[1,1]`, `[1,2]`, and `[1,3]`. Push each of these new nodes onto the stack too. That leaves the stack containing `[1,1]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,3]`, `[2]`, and `[3]`. Pop the next node. In this case, it's `[1,1]`. The length of this node is equal to `n`, so print it. Now pop again. That gives you `[1,2]`. Again, print it. Repeat to print `[1,3]`. Now when you pop again, you get `[2]`. That's not long enough, so we combine each element from `a` with the current node and push them onto the stack to yield `[2,1]`, `[2,2]`, and `[2,3]`.

Continue this process until the stack is empty and you will have printed every permutation of `n` items drawn from your array. What I've described is a recursive algorithm unrolled into an iterative one using a manually managed stack. You could simulate the same process using recursive calls instead of the stack if you prefer. Either way, you have to think basically recursively to solve the problem.